# Integer#times alternative that returns block?

Tags: ruby

I would like to create the following text:

```
"text0text1text2text3text4text5"
```

So I tried to do it with `.times`, but then I would need an auxiliary variable to hold the amounts, since `.times` returns the number of times it was executed.

I could do this way:

```
(0..5).inject(''){|a,b| a+"text#{b}"}
 => "text0text1text2text3text4text5"
```

However I feel that this code should be simpler.

So, what readable alternatives do I have to accomplish this?

Comment: `5.times.map { |x| "text#{x}" }.join`

Comment: Or just `[*"text#{a}".."text#{b}"].join`

Comment: Similar to @LeeJarvis you can use `map` on a range: `(0..5).map { |n| "text#{n}" }.join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is in a comment by @LeeJarvis

```
5.times.map { |x| "text#{x}" }.join
```

Answer (score 3):

*Notice that to have a range of number from `0` to `5` you are going to need a `6-times` loop, not `5`.*

You won't need any auxiliary variable:

```
6.times do |i|
    print "text#{i}"
end
```

will work just fine. The [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) method pass, to the attached block, the number of time the block executed from `0` to `n-1` times. The class `Fixnum` [doesn't even have](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html) (as of 2.0) a `times` method.

---

> Thanks. [...]. However, I don't want to print the text, I want to create a string.

Then the simplest way to do this is by using the `::new` constructor method of `Array` to create a temporary array of `5` strings and then join them together:

```
string = Array.new(6) { |i| "text#{i}" }.join
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, edited my post to change Fixnum by INteger. However, I don't want to *print* the text, I want to create a string.